# Show the sequence of functions (which can graphically be described as shrinking width triangles of height 1) converges pointwise to the zero function.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, pointwise-convergence

I would like some help in checking the following epsilon-delta proof I have written on a case-by-case basis for the pointwise convergence of the following function.

I am trying to prove that the sequence of functions $g_n(x)$ tends to $f(x) = 0$ in a pointwise fashion,

where $g_n(x) = 
\begin{cases} 
2nx & \text{for } x \in [0, \frac{1}{2n}) \\
-2n(x - \frac{1}{n}) & \text{for } x \in [\frac{1}{2n}, \frac{1}{n}) \\
0 & \text{for } x \in [\frac{1}{n}, 1]
\end{cases}$

I do understand and have internalised from reading other explanations (but I have not seen any case-by-case epsilon delta proofs for this online, which is what I am really trying to create myself as it would help my understanding) that for any point I pick $x$, the triangle of the graph, i.e. all non-zero values eventually pass to the left of it, so eventually $f_n(x)$ as I keep increasing $n$ and have a fixed $x$, reaches a point after which $f_n(x) = 0$, so $f_n$ converges pointwise for all nonzero $x$ (as we fix $x$ and then would find the right $N$ for it, i.e. when $x > \frac{1}{n}$ so $n > \frac{1}{x} = N$). But what pitfalls have I walked into when I try the following approach to showing pointwise convergence to the zero function?

My attempy for a case-by-case proof:

To show pointwise convergence, it means that I want to show that for any $x \in [0, 1]$, for any $\epsilon > 0$ I pick, there exists a natural number $N$ such that for a particular $x$, $|g_n(x) - 0| < \epsilon$.

For the case $x = 0$:
$g_n(x) = 0$ for all $n$ in natural numbers (so $N = 1$)

For the case $x \in [\frac{1}{2n}, \frac{1}{n})$: I have $|-2n(x - \frac{1}{n})-0| \leq 2n |x - \frac{1}{n}|$

Since $x$ is at most 1, $\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{3}, \ldots$ and $\frac{1}{n}$ is 1, $\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{3}, \ldots$

$2n |x - \frac{1}{n}| = 2n \left(\frac{1}{n} - x\right) = 2n | \frac{1}{n} - x | $, then for any $n$ greater than some natural number $N$,

$2n | \frac{1}{n} - x | = |2 - 2nx| \leq |2 - 2Nx| \leq |2| + |2Nx| = \epsilon$, then $N = \frac{\epsilon - 2}{2x}$ for $x \in [\frac{1}{2n}, \frac{1}{n}]$

For the case $x \in [0, \frac{1}{2n})$: I want to find an $N$, related to the $\epsilon$ I pick, such that for any $n$ greater than $N$, $|2nx - 0| < \epsilon$, so I try to bound $|2nx|, |2nx| \leq |2n(\frac{1}{2n})|$ as $x$ is at most $\frac{1}{2n}$, more specifically at most $\frac{1}{2}$, then $|2n(\frac{1}{2n})| \leq |2n(\frac{1}{2})| = |n|$

For the case $x \in [\frac{1}{n}, 1)$: $g_n(x) = 0$, so $N = 1$ as for any $x$, given any $\epsilon$, taking $N = 1$ means that $|g_n(x) - 0|$ will be less than $\epsilon$ for all $n \geq N$.

Comment: (I might be wrong, but to me) you seem to be having misconceptions / conceptual misunderstandings about how to prove this. What you need to do is show that for any $x, \epsilon$, there is a large enough $N$ such that for all $ n > N, |g_n(x) - 0 | < \epsilon$. 1/ That wasn't how you stated pointwise convergence definition. (Your $n$ had no relation to $N$, though that could be a typo.) 2/ You've not stated what $N$ is for a fixed $x$. (You've only done it conditionally on $ x \in [1/2n, 1/n], x \in [1/n, 1]$, which reinforces that point 1 likely isn't just a typo)

Comment: I did not initially relate n to N, but I believe this to be a typo that I made. As far as I know the steps I have taken above for the case $x \in [\frac{1}{2n}, \frac{1}{n})$, I have tried to find explicitly an N with the condition that n>N, to bound the difference between the sequence of functions for any fixed x in this range. So for a fixed x in the interval, given an epsilon, I can construct N (as shown in the formula I got), such that the difference will be less than epsilon. The function depends on which x I pick so I need to do the proof conditioning on where x is? @CalvinLin

Comment: "So for a fixed x in the interval, given an epsilon, I can construct N (as shown in the formula I got)" You did not do that explicitly. Or, you may think you did that, but that's not how we read it as. If so, you might need to add another line, like saying Given $x, \epsilon$, take $N = \max(f(x), h(x), p(x)) $, then for all $n > N$, $g_n(x) < \epsilon$.

Answer (score 0):

Your argument seems like overkill.

If $x > 0$, then there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $1/N < x$ (this follows directly from the Archimedean property, though you can certainly find a precise bound for $N$ with a little bit of basic algebra).  If $n > N$, then $g_n(x) = 0$.  Hence $g_n(x) \to 0$ for any $x > 0$.

On the other hand, $g_n(0) = 0$ for all $n$, and so $g_n(0) \to 0$.

Hence $g_n$ converges pointwise to zero.

Comment: In summary of your answer, we know $x$ is in $[0,1]$, therefore for a natural number $N$, $x \geq \frac{1}{N}$. If $n > N$, then $x \geq \frac{1}{N} > \frac{1}{n}$. This would mean $x > \frac{1}{n}$, so $x$ is not in $[0,\frac{1}{n})$. Therefore, for $n > N$, $g_n(x) = 0$. So, for any $x$, we can pick an $\epsilon$ such that we will be able to find an $N$ such that for all $n > N$, $|g_n(x) - 0| = 0 < \epsilon$. To find $N$, we want $x > \frac{1}{n}$, $n > \frac{1}{x} = N$, as $x$ is fixed. For the approach I took, which is"overkill", could you tell me where I went wrong?/Help me correct it?

Comment: @palt34 What do you mean "we can pick $\varepsilon$"?  I think that getting into the epsilonics of this argument is overkill, but remember that $\varepsilon$ is chosen *first*.  You *start* with $\varepsilon$, and then need to find $N$ large enough that $|g_n(x)| < \varepsilon$ for all $n > N$.  The thing is that $g_n(x)$ is eventually zero, so you just need to pick $N$ large enough...